How can I automatically indent on paste (without doing other formatting) with Monaco Editor?
I want to have in Monaco Editor a feature to automatically correctly indent the pasted code. E.g. if I paste a function inside another function, all subsequent lines of the pasted function should increase indentation to match the first line.
To some extent I managed to do it by setting formatOnPaste: true option, but I have two problems with this solution:

I only want to auto-indent, I do not want to do other auto-formatting which formatOnPaste does (e.g. adding some spaces).

format on paste works sometimes, but most of the times when I load the page, it just does not work. (Unless I select some text and run the Format Selection command from the context menu: after that the format on paste magically starts to work. So there is some strange bug in how it works.)


How to reproduce the problem:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            #container{
                height: 200px;
                border:1px solid grey;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
                
        <script src="monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
        <script>
            require.config({ paths: { vs: 'monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
            require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
                let monacoEditor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
                    language: 'javascript',
                    value: `function f(){
    
}
function g(){
    
}
`,
                    insertSpaces: false,
                    formatOnPaste: true,
                });
            });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

When I try to insert function g inside function f, I want this:
function f(){
    function g(){

    }
}

But instead, most of the times I get this:
function f(){
    function g(){
    
}   
}


Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
